# css background image issue in google site

Tags: google-sites

I am trying to specify a backgroud image for my google site, i have the following code inside the HTML Box

```
body {
  background: #372412;
  background-image:url('a/mysite/my/home/body.jpg');
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

i tried different options but the HTML Box Properties page just reports an error and i cannot get the image into my page.

i have one more image loaded using

```
<img src="/a/mysite/my/home/img11.jpg"
```

this image is shown properly so i suppose that the link is referring correctly.

can someone give me some direction to solve the above issue

Comment: Do you have a link to your google site?

Comment: well `body.jpg` and `img11.jpg` are two different files. Make sure `body.jpg` actually exists. Also try starting the background-image url with a `/` so `url('/a/mysite...')`

Comment: i even tried using img11.jpg and also / but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the background in Google Sites like this. The HTML Box is sanitized, and this CSS will probably go away.

Instead, use More -> Manage Site, then choose Themes, Colors & Fonts, and specify the background you wish to use.